# Unexpected token . while add css to jsx file

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

This is the error I am getting.

```
    /Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web
    app/src/components/AnswerDetail/AnswerDetail.css:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .example-appear {
                                                          ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
        at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
        at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28)
        at Module._extensions..js                 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
        at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app/src/components/AnswerDetail/AnswerDetail.jsx:12:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
        at Module._compile (/Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
        at Object.newLoader [as .jsx] (/Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app/src/App.jsx:3:1)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is how i imported my css:

```
    import AnswerDetailCss from './AnswerDetail.css';
```

This is in my webpack config file:

```
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
           'style-loader',
           { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried each and everything in different questions in stackoverflow but still not able to figure this out. I have using webpack 4, babel 7!

Edit::::::

File Structure. I am using import stte ment in AnswerDetail.jsx for AnswerDetail.css.

```
   <pre> /Users/gkapatia/git/bolo-mobile-web-app
    ├── data
    |  ├── api-real-url.js
    |  └── mock-answer.json
    ├── dist
    |  └── bundle.js
    ├── node_modules
    |  ├── all node mdules
    ├── out.txt
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    |  └── index.html
    ├── readme.md
    ├── server
    |  └── index.jsx
    ├── src
    |  ├── App.jsx
    |  ├── assests
    |  |  ├── bolo_logo.png
    |  |  └── bolo_white.png
    |  ├── components
    |  |  ├── AnswerDetail
    |  |  |  ├── AnswerDetail.css
    |  |  |  ├── AnswerDetail.jsx
    |  |  |  └── style.js
    |  |  └── common
    |  |     ├── ShareDialog
    |  |     |  ├── ShareDialog.css
    |  |     |  └── ShareDialog.jsx
    |  |     └── VideoPlayer
    |  |        └── VideoPlayer.jsx
    |  ├── getStore.js
    |  ├── index.jsx
    |  ├── reducers
    |  |  ├── answers.js
    |  |  └── index.js
    |  ├── sagas
    |  |  └── fetch-answers-saga.js
    |  └── styles
    |     └── App.css
    ├── util
    |  └── log.js
    ├── webpack.config.dev.babel.js
    ├── webpack.config.prod.babel.js
    ├── yarn-error.log
    └── yarn.lock
```

Edit:::::::::
this is my css file

```
    .example-appear {
      opacity: 0.01;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has been exported from css file.
Fix this...

```
import './AnswerDetail.css';
```

Modify the Config File...

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
       { loader: "style-loader" },
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
    ]
}
```

Comment: then you need to check your path and file name... Could you mention the file structure and file name here?

Comment: sure. wait a moment

Comment: can you have a look once agin @OneJeet

Comment: in which file you are importing this css file

Comment: AnswerDetail.jsx

Comment: import is happening that is why that error is coming but babel is not able to transform it, at that time error is coming?

Comment: this may occur due to some syntax error in css file. do check.

Comment: I have updated my question with css file. there is no error in that. style-loader and css-loader should recognise that i am importing a css file and covert it to module but they are not doing it.